# A possible security hole in client side OAuth2 flow for Google and Facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am creating a chrome extension, where i plan to use OAuth2 client side flow for authentication. As per the specs for both google and facebook, when i use client side flow, I get the access token as part of the hash part of the redirect_uri. Now my question is this -> what if a rogue extension transfers that access token to another extension on some other machine, which then uses that access token to get user details? I am quite novice with web development and ouath and would appreciate if somebody could clarify this doubt for me

Comment: If your extensions passes data to another service (without the users knowledge) then your extension is an evil one.  If your extension shares **any** user data without the user knowing about it then your extension is an evil one. To clarify : **don't be evil**

Comment: @Lix sorry i think you misunderstood my question. I have updated my question. what i meant to ask was isn't this a security bug in oauth client side flow as it only depends upon access tokens. A random extension could transfer my access tokens to some other machine which could than use it to fetch my data without my knowledge. I was just wondering whether such a thing could happen or not and in no way had any intention of implementing it.

Comment: Ok, this clears it up a bit.  Im not 100% certain of the nature of the extension as i have no knowledge of how they are structured and how they are able to communicate with each other.  Should the extension in question have a back-end server performing some actions, then the extension might not have to be in possession of any sensitive data.

Comment: @riteshKadmawala  Hii ritesh...Did you find d answer...did ypu implement d extension..I too am stuck with the similar problem..need to implement extension which logs user in by google oauth2 and interacts to my server, with access token form which my server obtains credentials..but its not happening..I've asked a question also but no responce form anyone...Please can you help me..[my question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357281/implementing-google-oauth2-for-chrome-extension-interecting-with-our-servers)

Comment: not sure if that helps but access token aren't supposed to have a long lifespan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook OAuth2 implementation requires that you use SSL (https) which means that other people cannot see that token unless you explicitly give it to them outside of the browser itself (or using an evil plugin, as noted).

There's a great post on this topic here: http://www.sociallipstick.com/?p=239

Answer (score 2):

Chrome extensions are sandboxed and data saved in your extension can not be accessed by another extension.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Chrome extensions have the ability to sniff your passwords, OAuth tokens, etc. if the user chooses to install them and grant them permissions to do that. You have to be careful with which extensions you choose to install!